# Merge two object lists in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics

I have two `List<T>`s which are both the same type. Is there an easy way to merge to the two sets without looping though both sets and merging them into a third?

#### Code

```
var myObject= new List<Core.MyObject>();
var myObject2= new List<Core.MyObject>();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txb.Text))
{
    var repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Core.RepositoryInterfaces.IRepository>();
    myObject= repository.GetWherePostCodeLike(txb.Text).ToList();
}

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddl.SelectedValue))
{
    var repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Core.RepositoryInterfaces.IRepository>();
    myObject2= repository.GetNearTownX(ddlLocations.SelectedValue).ToList();
}
```

It would have been nice to able able to just use the += on the second, but this is not allowed... Any ideas?

Comment: Those aren't `DataSet`s.

Comment: it is possible thorugh linq if im not mistaken. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298207/using-linq-to-merge-a-list-of-objects

Comment: Yea I know there not data sets I have made an edit to show this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the `Concat` (keeps duplicates) or `Union` (skips duplicates) LINQ methods

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> third = list.Concat(otherList);
```

To use `Union`, you'll need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to compare objects by value.  (or pass an `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`)

Comment: Thanks the Union in linq was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You got several alternatives.

You can concatenate them:

```
var combined = dataSet.Concat(dataSet2).ToList();
```

You can add one to the other:

```
dataSet.AddRange(dataSet2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
var merged = dataSet.Concat(dataSet2).ToList();
```