# trim away duplicates using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am working with an API that is returning duplicate Ids. I need to insert these values into my database using the EF. Before trying to add the objects I want to trim away any duplicates.

I have a small example of the code I am trying to write.

```
  var itemsToImport = new List<Item>(){};
        itemsToImport.Add(new Item() { Description = "D-0", Id = 0 });            
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            itemsToImport.Add(new Item(){Id = i,Description = "D-"+i.ToString()});
        }

        var currentItems = new List<Item>
                        {
                            new Item() {Id = 1,Description = "D-1"},
                            new Item(){Id = 3,Description = "D-3"}
                        };
        //returns the correct missing Ids
        var missing = itemsToImport.Select(s => s.Id).Except(currentItems.Select(s => s.Id));


        //toAdd contains the duplicate record. 
        var toAdd = itemsToImport.Where(x => missing.Contains(x.Id));
        foreach (var item in toAdd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Description);
        }
```

What do I need to change to fix my variable "toAdd" to only return a single record even if there is a repeat?

Comment: Do the items with the duplicate ID's have exactly the same data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by grouping by the Id and then selecting the first item in each group.

```
var toAdd = itemsToImport
              .Where(x => missing.Contains(x.Id));
```

becomes

```
var toAdd = itemsToImport
              .Where(x => missing.Contains(x.Id))
              .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
              .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use DistinctBy from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com), as recommended by Jon Skeet in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2298230/385844

The call would look something like this:

```
var toAdd = itemsToImport.Where(x => missing.Contains(x.Id)).DistinctBy(x => x.Id);
```

If you'd rather not (or can't) use MoreLINQ for some reason, DistinctBy is fairly easy to implement yourself:

```
static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, TKey> projection)
{
    var set = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (var item in sequence)
        if (set.Add(projection(item)))
            yield return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Distinct` function. You'll need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Item` (Given they contain the same data) though.

Or use `FirstOrDefault` to get the first Item with the matching Id back.

```
itemsToImport.Where(x => missing.Contains(x.Id)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: this way you would get just one item instead of the whole collection - are you missing a groupBy ?

Comment: Interpreting his question (I might did it wrong) he wants to have toAdd return just one value.